# Sequential Criteria of Limit Points in Hausdorff Spcaes

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits

By the sequential criteria, I convey that :
A point p of set S is limit point of S if there exists a sequence of distinct points in S that converge to p.

I understand that if the space is metriziable, then this holds.
But for general spaces I haven't been able to find a counter example.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at big spaces. As in, really big. Consider [the long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) $L=\omega_1\times[0,1)$ with the order topology and let $X=L \cup \{\infty\}$ be its compactification (the extended long line), i.e. $\infty$ is greater than any other element of $L$. Let $S=X$. Then $\infty$ is a limit point of $S$ but no sequence (of distinct points) converges to $\infty$. It is just too far away. That's because [cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality) of $\omega_1$ is uncountable (at least assuming ZFC).

Note that there is a proper generalization of that concept. In a topological space, $p$ is a limit point if and only if there is a **[net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics))** of distinct points convergent to $p$, not a sequence. The example above shows that some sequences, unlike nets, just don't reach far enough.

Typical topological space, where we can replace nets with sequences when talking about limit points, is a [first countable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space). In general such spaces are known as [Fréchet–Urysohn spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Urysohn_space).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not acquainted with the ordinal numbers so I might not be able to fully comprehend or appreciate your answer. Nonetheless, thanks for answering.

Comment: @user499096 yeah, the example is quite abstract, counterintuitive and difficult to understand. But is also pathological, you will very rarely see such spaces in real maths. It is only there to remind people to be very careful with some definitions.

Comment: One more thing, since you didn't mention, the space formed is Hausdroff ?

Comment: @user499096 yes, it is. [The order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology) on ordinals is always Hausdorff (even normal), and so are products and compactifications. Btw in the article about Fréchet–Urysohn spaces there are other examples of such pathological spaces.

Comment: Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a simple example that does not use ordinals. Let $Y=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, and let $\tau$ be the following topology on $\Bbb R$

$$\tau=\wp(Y)\cup\{\Bbb R\setminus F:F\subseteq Y\text{ is countable}\}\,;$$

that is, points of $Y$ are isolated, and a set $U\subseteq\Bbb R$ is an open nbhd of $0$ if and only if $0\in U$ and $\Bbb R\setminus U$ is countable. It’s easy to check that $\langle\Bbb R,\tau\rangle$ is Hausdorff and that $0\in\operatorname{cl}_\tau Y$.

However, if $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is any sequence in $Y$, the set $\Bbb R\setminus\{y_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is an open nbhd of $0$ that contains **no** points of the sequence, so no sequence in $Y$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for this example. But in the 4th line, it should be R/U is countable rather than R/F.

Comment: @user499096: Oops! You’re absolutely right; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the ordinal example (which is a very standard one, and I usually reduce it to just the ordinal $\omega_1 + 1$ in the order topology):

Let $X=[0,1]^I$ where $I$ is an uncountable set, in the product topology.
For $f \in X$ let the *support* $s(f)$ of $f$ be defined by $s(f)=\{i \in I\mid f(i) \neq 0\}$, and define the subspace $S$ of $X$ by:

$$S = \{f \in X\mid s(f) \text{ is at most countable }\}$$

Then $S$ is dense in $X$ (so all functions are limit points of $S$), but no sequence of elements from $S$ can converge to a point $g \notin S$. So this is quite a strong example of even a compact Hausdorff space where the sequential criterion fails. BTW $S$ is also a sequentially compact subspace of $X$ which is not closed in $S$ and moreover $X$ itself is *not* sequentially compact despite being compact.